# Trouble with VC locking and unlocking permissions

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am having trouble locking a vc. When i go to run the command it says interaction failed, but it doesn't give any error. i tried adding  `else: await interaction.response.send_message(content='You are not the author of this channel.')` That just gave that text, and tried removing channel in `interaction.user.voice` and yet still nothing.

```
   @app_commands.command(name='lock', description='Locks the VC you are currently in')
    async def lock(self, interaction:discord.Interaction):
        channel = interaction.user.voice.channel
        if interaction.user.voice is None:

            await interaction.response.send_message(content='You are not in a voice channel.')

        

        if channel.id in data and data[channel.id] == interaction.user.id:
            overwrite = channel.overwrites_for(interaction.guild.default_role)
            overwrite.connect = False
            await channel.set_permissions(interaction.guild.default_role, overwrite=overwrite)
            await interaction.response.send_message(content='VC has been locked, only Moderators and Admins can join.')
```

Comment: Please specific what exactly `data` is and how you define it. Does it give out the first answer or is it not doing that at all?

Comment: i only have {} in data because i reallly dont know how to use dicts even with looking at docs and it doesnt do anything except give interaction failed.

Comment: Does it give out "*You are not in a voice channel*" if you are not in a voice channel though?

Comment: yes it gives that text, but nothing else

Answer (score 0):

As your dict can be empty, there may be `KeyErrors` that you are not aware of/don't catch.

While your `overwrite` method does not look wrong in the first place, you still may use a different and more reliable approach when it comes to managing permissions.

```py
try:
    if channel.id in data and data[channel.id] == interaction.user.id:
        await interaction.response.send_message(content='Your message')
    else:
        data[channel.id] = interaction.user.id # Add the ID into the dict
        await interaction.response.send_message(content='Your message')
except KeyError:
    data[channel.id] = interaction.user.id # Add the ID into the dict
    await interaction.response.send_message(content='Your message')

overwrites = {
    interaction.guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(connect=False)
}
await channel.edit(overwrites=overwrites) # Edit the channel regardless of the case
```

In this code, we properly handle possible `KeyError` errors and add the ID of the channel to the dict.

Please note that the dict implementation is rather simple and the ID in the dict always gets replaced with a new one. If you want a more complex implementation, you may take a look at that yourself ([How To Add to a Dictionary in Python](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/python-add-to-dictionary))

We also update the channel permission regardless of the case. If you only want to edit it in special cases, you may want to adapt the code as well!